# How to use option-delete in my .inputrc for readline

Tags: bash, readline

I'd like to configure my shell so that when I do 'option-backspace' then I delete the previous word.

I know I have to put something like

```
"\eDEL": backward-kill-word
```

in my .inputrc, but I can't figure out the exact thing that goes on the left.  I also cannot figure out where to look this up.

What should I put in my .inputrc?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
"\e\b": backward-kill-word
```

The syntax is explained in the Bash manual, under [Readline Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File).

`\b` is the escape for backspace.

Instead of escapes, you should also be able to use key names:

```
Meta-Rubout: backward-kill-word
```